# Why the "_.orderBy" function does not sort the results?

Tags: sorting, lodash

I wanted to do data sorting and I don't know why it doesn't work. I have been struggling with this for several hours and I still don't know what is wrong. Could someone tell me why the "_.orderBy" function does not sort the results?

```
<template>
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index">
                    <a href="#" @click="sortBy(index)">{{ column }}</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="user in orderedUsers" :key="user.id">
                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
            </tR>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                users: [
                    {name: 'Andrew', age: 100},
                    {name: 'Bella', age: 200},
                    {name: 'Cylerion', age: 300},
                ],
                columns: {
                    name: 'User Name',
                    age: 'User Age'
                },
                sortKey: 'name',
                reverse: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            orderedUsers: function () {
                return _.orderBy(this.users, this.sortKey, this.reverse)
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sortBy: function(sortKey) {
                this.reverse = (this.sortKey == sortKey) ? ! this.reverse : false;

                this.sortKey = sortKey;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

My library: Lodash 4.6.0.

Comment: Please update tags on your question to clarify what `_.orderBy` refers to: library + version. Note both lodash and underscore use the same naming convention.

Comment: Ok, understand. My library is: Lodash 4.6.0.

Comment: Third argument has to be an array of strings `'asc'|'desc'` which sets the order of each iteratee. If you skip it, all iteratees are asumed` `'asc'`. In your case, since you only have 1 iteratee, it has to be either `['asc']` (default - so you can skip third argument altogether) or `['desc']`. [Docs here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy).

Comment: ok, it works. Thank you for your help